# Is it possible to remove the border between 2 cells in a TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I want to remove the border between 2 cells, and similarly, have a border around them if they were in the middle of a TableLayoutPanel. Say a 5x5 grid, and it was cells (2,3) and (2,4) how would this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239179/draw-borders-around-some-cells-in-a-tablelayoutpanel

Answer (score 0):

Change the [ColumnSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171687%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the controls inside the panel.

Comment: could you give me an example of the code?

Comment: check [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2006/04/05/winforms-autolayout-basics-tablelayoutpanel.aspx)