# TableLayoutPanel cell border style with columnspan

Tags: c#, border, tablelayoutpanel

I have a tablelayoutpanel which I create programmatically. My problem is I have some textboxes which have columnspan value like that image:[image]

I do not want to see cutted border lines as seen on second, third, fourth..rows. I tried that solution ([Draw borders around some cells in a tablelayoutpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239179/draw-borders-around-some-cells-in-a-tablelayoutpanel)) already but I do not know how to apply to my control, beacuse It draws very first cell border lines only.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Show us the code that you use to add the textboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing your TextBox control inside a Panel with these settings:

```
panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel1.Margin = new Padding(0);
```

then just center your TextBox control inside of the panel.